# Shortcut to turn a ONE element dict into ONE tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

There are dozens of questions on turning a Python dict with some number of elements into a list of tuples. I am looking for a shortcut to turn a one element dict into a tuple.

Ideally, it would:

1. Be idiomatic and simple (ie, not a subclass of `dict`, not a function, etc).
2. Throw an error if there are more that one element in the dict.
3. Support multiple assignment by tuple unpacking.
4. Not destroy the `dict`.

I am looking for a shortcut to do this (that is not destructive to the dict):

```
k,v=unpack_this({'unknown_key':'some value'})
```

`*` does not work here.

I have come up with these that work:

```
k,v=next(iter(di.items()))   # have to call 'iter' since 'dict_items' is not
```

Or:

```
k,v=(next(((k,v) for k,v in di.items())))
```

Or even:

```
k,v=next(zip(di.keys(), di.values()))
```

Finally, the best **I** can come up with:

```
k,v=list(di.items())[0]      # probably the best...
```

Which can be wrapped into a function if I want a length check:

```
def f(di):
    if (len(di)==1): return list(di.items())[0]
    raise ValueError(f'Too many items to unpack. Expected 2, got {len(di)*2}')
```

These methods seem super clumsy and none throw an error if there is more than one element.

Is there an idiomatic shortcut that I am missing?

Comment: I imagine that structural pattern matching will be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> d.popitem()
('a', 1)
```

This will return the pair associated with the *last* key added, with no error error if the `dict` has multiple keys, but the same length check you've made in your function `f` can be used.

```
def f(di):
    if len(di) == 1:
        return d.popitem()
    raise ValueError(f'Dict has multiple keys')
```

Comment: Simple! But destructive to `d`

Comment: Should probably add that to your list of constraints :)

Comment: However, I think the expectation to raise an error if there is more than one key is a bit of a tall order.

Comment: One could do: `{**di}.popitem()` to keep from altering `di`

Comment: *However, I think the expectation to raise an error if there is more than one key is a bit of a tall order.* Maybe. I was just seeing that tuple assignment of the form `v1,v2=[1,2,3]` is common and and strict (that is an `ValueError`). Yet there is no way to parallel that with a dict.

Comment: I guess that `{**d}.popitem() if len(d)==1 else (None,None)` is as close as I can get. The key thing you gave me was `{}.popitem()` Thanks!

Comment: `k,v={**d}.popitem() if len(d)==1 else ['too','many','values']` is the best...

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to what my conclusions were at the end.

Comment: Could you post a separate answer of your own (which you can accept if you like)? I'm not a big fan of using an arbitrary string just to force a similar exception to the one you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Why not :

```
next(iter(d.items())) if len(d)==1 else (None,None)
```

Answer (score 0):

@chepner has the right approach with `.popitem()`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> d.popitem()
('a', 1)        # d is now {}
```

This will return the pair associated with the *last* key added, with no error error if the `dict` has multiple keys. It will also destroy `d`.

You can keep `d` intact by using this idiom to create a new dict and pop off the last item from the new dict created with `{**d}`:

```
>>> {**d}.popitem()
('a', 1)
>>> d
{'a': 1}
```

As far as a 1 line unpackable tuple that throws an error if the dict has more than one item, you can use a Python conditional expression with an alternate that throws the error desired:

```
# success: k=='a' and v==1
>>> d={'a':1}
>>> k,v={**d}.popitem() if len(d)==1 else 'wrong number of values'


# len(d)!=1 - pass a string to k,v which is too long
>>> d={'a':1,'b':2}
>>> k,v={**d}.popitem() if len(d)==1 else 'wrong number of values'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If you object to different types being passed, you could do:

```
>>> k,v={**d}.popitem() if len(d)==1 else {}.fromkeys('too many keys').items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```